# Check if username exist with AJAX

Tags: ajax, user-registration, validation

I've created a custom registration form for a WordPress MultiSite installation. It allows registrations of new blogs and users. I want to check with ajax if a given username is available. This is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'pb_ajax_add_js' );

function pb_ajax_add_js() {

// add script to the footer
wp_enqueue_script( 'pb_ajax',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/script.js',
    array('jquery'), BOJ_ARM_VERSION, true
);

//Get protocol of the current page.
$protocol = isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

// Display the admin-ajax.php using the same protocol as the current page.
$params = array(
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', $protocol )
);
wp_localize_script( 'pb_ajax', 'pb_ajax', $params );
}
```

Server side request handling:

```
// Ajax request handling.
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_boj_arm_ajax', 'pb_check_username');
add_action('wp_ajax_boj_arm_ajax', 'pb_check_username');

function pb_check_username() {
$username = $_REQUEST['usr'];
echo $username;

die();
}
```

And jQuery script(note: in this version, validation is after click link)

```
(function($) {
    $('.check-username').click(function(){
        var link = this;
        $(link).html('sprawdzanie...');
        // href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}"
        var usr = $("#site-addres-input").attr('value');

        var data = {
            action: 'boj_arm_ajax',
            usr: usr
        };

        $.get(boj_arm.ajaxurl, data, function(data){
            $(link).after(data).remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Script isn't complete. It Must check if the username exists, and return true or false. Can You help me Please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your jQuery selector:

```
var usr = $("#site-addres-input").attr('value');
```

Will get the default value of the input element.  Typically this will be blank, because you're not setting it ahead of time.  You need to use:

```
var usr = $("#site-addres-input").val();
```

I'm also noticing that you're using `#site-addres-input`, but "address" has two s at the end.  Not sure if this is also causing you a problem or not ...

Comment: Iam using site addres as a username(new blog addres is equal to username). But this dont change anything...

Comment: The other thing you'll need to do is change `$.get` to `$.post` in order to send your data to WordPress. But aside from the changes I've recommended, we can't recommend anything else without seeing the actual HTML markup you're trying to hit against.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function: [`username_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists) to check if the user exists.
Like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_boj_arm_ajax', 'pb_check_username');
add_action('wp_ajax_boj_arm_ajax', 'pb_check_username');

function pb_check_username() {
    $username = $_REQUEST['usr'];
    if(username_exists($username))
        echo 1;
    else
        echo 0;
    die();
}
```

Please read the codex for the correct usage of this function as you'll need to include a file.

Comment: Sitll dont work. It Don't echo anything.